# Converting gromacs to Amberfiles - ParmEd

Tags: python, error-handling, file-conversion, chemistry, amber-smalltalk

I am finding this error when I'm trying to prepare amber files using gromacs files.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "/ichec/packages/amber/18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ParmEd-3.0.0+57.g74a84d30-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/parmed/formats/registry.py", line 214, in load_file
return cls(filename, *args, **kwargs)
File "/ichec/packages/amber/18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ParmEd-3.0.0+57.g74a84d30-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/parmed/gromacs/gromacstop.py", line 251, in **init**
self.read(fname, defines, parametrize)
File "/ichec/packages/amber/18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ParmEd-3.0.0+57.g74a84d30-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/parmed/gromacs/gromacstop.py", line 444, in read
'template defined' % molname)
parmed.exceptions.GromacsError: Structure contains ea10 molecules, but no template defined

I need help on this!

Thanks,

I tried to update python version on my system but still failed. I want an explanation what does the error mean